# Pagination resetting to page 1 after a modal popup and callback from service to the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap pagination to layout the page. The value of one of the columns is a link and when clicked, opens a modal with a list. The page(actually a table laid out as pages) is resetting to page 1 just before the modal opens and the modal pops up.

The callback from the service to the controller is resetting it! Can anyone help me with how to set the page to currentPage(stay on current page) in the callback from the service. Thanks!!
Controller side code

```
var result = angularService.getResults(id, $scope.value, function(response){
    $scope.results = response.data;
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'displayUrl',              
        controller: 'angularCtrl',          
    });
});

Service side code
getResults: function(id, value, callback){      
    var url = 'url';
    $http.get(url).then(function(response){
        results = response.data;
        callback(response); //this resets the page to Page1
     })
},
```

Please dont mind if the question is not in right format, am new here!!

Answer (score 0):

set `reloadOnSearch` to false, [doc link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)